# Connect Database to asp.net MVC 4 default roles tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a created a database on my SQLEXPRESS server called Database.

In this database are the default tables generated by mvc. They are:

UserProfile
webpages_Membershio
webpages_OAuthMembership
webpages_Roles
webpages_UsersInRoles

Now when i run my application I can register a user and login. and that works. So the application has access to these tables some how.

Now I am really struggling to write a view where i can add additional roles to the system.

How can I now access the database as well?

Sorry for the noob questions, But i have tried creating a dbclass under models and representing it there. But i am only having trouble and my thoughts are if the system can access it to log me in, cant i use the same method which it does?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SimpleMembership.

If so, why not check out the following article. Should give you some good pointers.

[Adding Security and Membership to an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership)